# Declaration Of Maximum Object of Control In WinForm Class

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, visual-studio

I want to know If I require  to declare 1000+ object of controls in class then how to declare it. I have class like below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

namespace FinApps
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {   
    //Global Area Of Class
    // Maximum Limit of Declaration is 1000-

        private FinAppsUserControl.FinAppsUserControl side1; //global object of control

        public Form1()
        {
            side1 = new FinAppsUserControl.FinAppsUserControl(); //Initialization
            InitializeComponent();

            this.panel2.Controls.Add(side1);

        }
    }
}
```

If my requirement  to declare 1000+ global object of controls like above in global area of form1 class then how to fulfill it?.

Comment: If you have a 1000 controls that live inside a single control/form, you may have to reconsider how you place your controls. Controls can be nested inside others.

Comment: @LightStriker, So If there are two UserControls and they are depended on each other than there are no need to declare both on winform application just declare one of them on winform and other have to set in side of usercontrol1 from usercontrol application?.

Comment: ...If so then how can you set UserControl2 on winform?.

Comment: Each control contains a list named `Controls` which is the controls nested inside it. For example, a button can be nested inside a list control. If you take a webbroswer, all the tab are control, but they are nested inside a tabs list control, which is inside a toolbar, etc.

Comment: @LightStriker, Thanks for your help now i got it. do you mean to use "Controls.Add()" to parent for listed child controls. Isn't it?.

Comment: Exact. No control is rendered unless it has a valid parent... And parenting is automatically set when you add a control to the parent's `Controls` list.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare it easily:

```
List<Control> _controls = new List<Control>();

// in Load method (pseudocode)
//SuspendLayout
//add 1000+ controls in a loop
//ResumeLayout
```

But you are doing something wrong. If you can split your controls into reusable groups, use UserControl to encapsulate small piece of functionality. Do you have to use WinForms? It is relatively easy to do that in WPF using DataTemplates.

Please reconsider what you want to achieve, that amount of controls introduces significant problems for localization, maintenance, etc.